# I am trying to recover data using checkpoint in spark structured streaming. But getting the following error

Tags: apache-spark

I am learning structured streaming. I have a csv file in a folder which have order data. Trying to implement recovering using checkpoint concept. i added one more file to the input folder and restart the driver but getting the following error.

This query does not support recovering from checkpoint location. Delete C:/Users/q794089/Documents/Hadoop/SparkScala/recoveringcheckpoint/checkpoint/offsets to start over.

Here is the code. Please let me know if anything wrong with the code

```
val schema = StructType(Array(StructField("transactionId", StringType), StructField("customerId", StringType), StructField("itemId", StringType), StructField("amountPaid", DoubleType)))

val fileStreamDf = sparkSession.readStream.option("header", true).schema(schema).csv("C:\\Users\\q794089\\Documents\\Hadoop\\SparkScala\\recoveringcheckpoint\\order")

//create stream from folder
val countDs = fileStreamDf.groupBy("customerId").sum("amountPaid")

val query =
  countDs.writeStream
    .format("console")
    .option("checkpointLocation", "C:\\Users\\q794089\\Documents\\Hadoop\\SparkScala\\recoveringcheckpoint\\checkpoint")
    .outputMode(OutputMode.Complete())

query.start().awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should have been solved by: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21667. Check the fixed releases.